# Docker configuration for Node project

Tags: node.js, docker, npm

My Node.js project won't load on docker.

As you can see the **index** can't load.

Here is the code:https://github.com/tech-387/spartan-apps-admin-console-frontend

Here is the error I get:

> > npm@1.0.0 start /home/node/app
> >     node ./bin/www
>
> internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:584
>       throw err;
>       ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module './src/Presentation/viewModel/index'
>       at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582:15)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:508:25)
>       at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
>       at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
>       at /home/node/app/app.js:29:18
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at Object. (/home/node/app/app.js:28:26)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32) npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! npm@1.0.0 start: `node
>   ./bin/www` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR!  npm ERR! Failed at the
>   npm@1.0.0 start script. npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with
>   npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   /root/.npm/_logs/2019-05-09T09_13_02_678Z-debug.log

And here is my docker file:

```
FROM node:10-alpine

WORKDIR /home/node/app

COPY app.js /home/node/app
COPY bin /home/node/app/bin
COPY config /home/node/app/config
COPY public /home/node/app/public
COPY scratch /home/node/app/scratch
COPY src /home/node/app/src
COPY package.json /home/node/app
COPY package-lock.json /home/node/app

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 3000

# Start the app
CMD npm start
```

Comment: CMD [ "npm", "start" ] Add this

Comment: is your app running perfectly without Docker setup?

Comment: Yes it is running

Comment: Do you mind putting this sample on git. I would like to give a try

Comment: I can not put the project it's private

Comment: Completely understand!.  just dummy folder structure with hello world example

Comment: I use express if that something means to you.

Comment: Just to double-check, how are you running the container?  Can you add your `docker run` command to the question?

Comment: @DavidMaze I use docker run -p 8080:3000 -d .....